# I can't declare function within namespace scope with global name (gcc)

Tags: c++, gcc, namespaces

I am trying to declare my own "CreateWindow" in my "wnd" namespace, but gcc say "error: macro "CreateWindowA" requires 11 arguments, but only 1 given|".
Please, tell me how to get it properly.
Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

namespace wnd
{


void CreateWindow()
{
}

}
```

Comment: windows.h has a `CreateWindow()` function in it.

Comment: Sounds like that evil header defines the name as a macro. The only thing you can do is choose another name, or not include that header. I'd recommend the latter, unless you need to support Windows for some reason.

Comment: @NathanOliver: No it doesn't

Comment: @NathanOliver you mean, a macro?

Comment: I need this header for some functions (CreateWindowEx etc.). I will use other name. Thanks all

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Sorry it is actually in winuser.h but you are supposed to include windows.h https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @NathanOliver: Nope, it is not a function (scroll to the bottom of that page! Admittedly the rest of it is exceedingly misleading). And that's the problem.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Now I have one more thing to add to my list of things Microsoft drives me crazy with

Comment: @NathanOliver yes indeed yes indeed!

Answer (score 4):

The name `CreateWindow` already exists in the Windows API. Unfortunately, your namespacing (nice try!) has no effect as the original symbol is a *macro*.

There is no good workaround for this as long as you include `windows.h`. You will have to choose a different name for your function.

Answer (score 1):

There's a macro named `CreateWindow` clashing with your function name.

The best thing to do would be to just **change your function name**.

If you insist you can `#undef CreateWindow`, which is problematic since it will cancel that macro for every file that will include yours.

So you'll need to stack it and bring it back:

```
#pragma push_macro("CreateWindow")
#undef CreateWindow

void CreateWindow()
{
}

#pragma pop_macro("CreateWindow")
```

*And it will still be only visible within the `pragma` scope.

Comment: OK, good idea. But then you'll have to do it at each call site, too. Seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: Arnon Zilca, thanks! It's seems that  it does not pass this trick with the macro, only with functions